# How to solve merge conflicts so that just two files are shown in meld

Tags: git, git-merge, meld, mergetool

I'm using meld as mergetool for git and I'm wondering why meld always shows three files when I run `git mergetool`. I would prefer to see only two files in meld (the HEAD version and the version from the other branch that I want to merge). 
Is it possible to configure meld so that it does the merge with only two files?

This is my current `.gitconfig` file:

```
[merge]
    tool = meld
[mergetool]
    prompt = false
[mergetool "meld"]
    trustExitCode = true
cmd = open -W -a Meld --args --auto-merge \"$PWD/$LOCAL\" \"$PWD/$BASE\" \"$PWD/$REMOTE\" --output=\"$PWD/$MERGED\"
```

Comment: Could you show the output from `git mergetool` and `git status`, and possibly other things we might need to be able to help you?

Comment: I have always found to be a great thing the 3-way merge to better understand changes made by others and easy the merge. I really don't get it why to make it's job harder...

Comment: As @Philippe says, you probably do want to see the three files; when you're performing a 3-way merge using meld, push the changes all the way across (rather than to the center) and it'll be a bit more obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current `.gitconfig` runs Meld in a three-way directory compare between `$LOCAL`, `$BASE`, and `$REMOTE`. If you want set this up as a two-way compare (assuming you don't want to compare against `$REMOTE`), simply change your config to (i.e. remove the `$REMOTE` command argument)

```
cmd = open -W -a Meld --args --auto-merge \"$PWD/$LOCAL\" \"$PWD/$BASE\" --output=\"$PWD/$MERGED\"
```